# FB applications NO LONGER able to be added to pages as TABS?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

(please do not vote down unless you have created a NEW facebook app and tried this)

THIS IS A BREAKING CHANGE JUST NOW WITH FB!

If you create a FB app, in order to add the app's tab to a page, you would visit the application page, then click "Add to my page".

HOWEVER, as of just a few minutes ago... if you create a facebook application... you must manually create a FB page to be associated with the app (this is done through advanced settings).

After you create the App page, if you visit it, and try to click "Add to my page". the result is that the app is added NOT as a tab, but added under a new section called "likes".

Please see screenshot of the 2 red circles, 1 showing where the app SHOULD be as a tab, the other red circle showing where is it currently.

I just want the app to be added as a TAB not this new section. can anyone please advise?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add it manually

To add the App to your page use the following link:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=[APP_ID]&display=popup&next=https://[URL_TO_YOUR_APP_ON_YOUR SERVER]

more info

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/

Comment: thanks alex. that did it! follow up question. if you add the app to a page... generally you can use the PHP SDK to spit out the signed request.. such as $sr = $facebook->getSignedRequest(); however this is returning empty on newly created apps. any idea why?